# Oracle 10g Supplied Packages Unavailable

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I am a student learning PL/SQL. I have a local installation of 10g I am running my queries against. Whenever I attempt to use DBMS_ALERT, DBMS_PIPE or other default packages, I get an "invalid SQL" message. I have tried the queries in TOAD and SQL+Plus with the same results. This would lead me to believe these packages are not installed, or not accessable to my user session. I am using the 'SYS' user login, so I wouldn't think permissions would be an issue.

Could someone please educate me on how to make these packages avaialble? I was under the impression they were provided by default?

Thank you very much,

Kyle

Comment: Please show us the SQL you are running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those packages may simply not be installed. If you'd like to install them, look in the $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin directory and run the scripts as SYS.  I included files references for the packages you listed above.

DBMS_ALERT
  dbmsalrt.sql and prvtalrt.plb

DBMS_PIPE
  dbmspipe.sql and prvtpipe.plb

Answer (score 4):

One thing you might be doing wrong is trying to call a PL/SQL function or procedure outside of a PL/SQL block.  You may need to wrap the calls to procedures in `begin` and `end`, for example:

```
SQL> dbms_lock.sleep(1);
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "dbms_lock...." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> begin dbms_lock.sleep(1); end;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

(The single `/` on a line by itself tells SQL*Plus that that's the end of the input.  Normally, SQL*Plus uses a semicolon to mark the end of a statement.  However, PL/SQL can contain semicolons, and if SQL*Plus recognises that you're entering PL/SQL, it will wait for the single `/` on its own before passing its input to the database.)

Another possible reason for the errors you are seeing is that you are trying to call a stored procedure within a query.  This isn't possible, since a stored procedure returns no result.  Admittedly, the error you get if you do try to call a procedure within a query isn't particularly helpful:

```
SQL> select dbms_alert.register('test') from dual;
select dbms_alert.register('test') from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "DBMS_ALERT"."REGISTER": invalid identifier
```

The reason for this error is likely to be that Oracle doesn't bother looking among stored procedures for the name `dbms_alert.register`, and so instead gives a generic 'I couldn't find this name' error.

If your problem isn't either of these I've described, please let me know.